# Generate and use unique name for PrimeFaces remoteCommand

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, composite-component

I understand that for PrimeFaces components with the `widgetVar` property, I can use the `p:widgetVar('myComponentId')` to get a `widgetVar` derived from the component's ID. It would be nice if the same sort of functionality existed for `<p:remoteCommand/>` so I could have multiple instances of the same type of composite component that uses `<p:remoteCommand/>`. I initially tried the `widgetVar` function, but then realized it won't work.

```xml
<p:remoteCommand id="previousCycleCommand"
                 actionListener="#{cc.selectPreviousCycle()}"
                 update=":#{cc.clientId}:updateable"
                 partialSubmit="false"/>

<p:button id="previousCycleButton"
          icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-w"
          onclick="#{p:widgetVar('previousCycleCommand')}();"/>
```

Is there any PrimeFaces functionality I can use to derive a remote command's name from its fully expanded ID?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the current client ID to create a unique ID? Since every composite component should be an unique naming container, the concatenated ID should be unique too.

```xml
<p:remoteCommand id="#{cc.clientId}_previousCycleCommand"
             actionListener="#{cc.selectPreviousCycle()}"
             update=":#{cc.clientId}:updateable"
             partialSubmit="false"/>

<p:button id="previousCycleButton"
      icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-w"
      onclick="#{cc.clientId}_previousCycleCommand();"/>
```

Comment: The problem with that is `#{cc.clientId_previousCycleCommand()}` is not guaranteed to be a valid JavaScript identifier, especially in the case that the composite component is instantiated within a naming container. I supposed I could make my own `p:widgetVar`-like method for this purpose.

Comment: Oh sorry. You're right. Beside that I totally messed up with the remoteCommand's id- and name-attribute.